# Query on Microsoft Graph API Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-api

I want to pull emails by Graph API from client inbox using python.
I started with a tutorial and successfully experimented over my personal inbox.

My problem,
Every time my code generates an authorization URL.
I have to browse through it (using web browser library) , sign in using my credentials and copy paste the authorization code for generating access token.
Which is a lot of manual work every time.

Question :
Is there a way to automate the whole process of token generation ?
Such that my client only shares his application id and client secret, and email is pulled without his sign in credentials ?

My code is attached below -

---

```
import msal 
from msal import PublicClientApplication 
import webbrowser
import requests
import pandas as pd


APPLICATION_ID="app id"
CLIENT_SECRET="client secret"
authority_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/'
base_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/'
endpoint_url = base_url+'me'
SCOPES = ['Mail.Read','Mail.ReadBasic']


client_instance = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id = APPLICATION_ID,client_credential = CLIENT_SECRET,authority = authority_url)
authorization_request_url=client_instance.get_authorization_request_url(SCOPES)
#print(authorization_request_url)

# browsing authorization request URL for retrieving authorization code.   
webbrowser.open(authorization_request_url,new=True)

# Manually pasting authorization code.
authorization_code='authorization code from authorization URL'  

access_token = client_instance.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(code=authorization_code,scopes=SCOPES)

access_token_id=access_token['access_token']

# Rest of the codes are for hitting the end point and retrieving the messages
```

Any help with code suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to authenticate only with a clientId and clientSecret, without any user context, you should leverage a [client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) flow.

You can check [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/tree/master/1-Call-MsGraph-WithSecret) official MS sample that uses the same MSAL library to handle the client credentials flow. It is quite straightforward, as you can see below:

```
import sys  # For simplicity, we'll read config file from 1st CLI param sys.argv[1]
import json
import logging

import requests
import msal


# Optional logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

config = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))

# Create a preferably long-lived app instance which maintains a token cache.
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    config["client_id"], authority=config["authority"],
    client_credential=config["secret"],
    # token_cache=...  # Default cache is in memory only.
                       # You can learn how to use SerializableTokenCache from
                       # https://msal-python.rtfd.io/en/latest/#msal.SerializableTokenCache
    )

# The pattern to acquire a token looks like this.
result = None

# Firstly, looks up a token from cache
# Since we are looking for token for the current app, NOT for an end user,
# notice we give account parameter as None.
result = app.acquire_token_silent(config["scope"], account=None)

if not result:
    logging.info("No suitable token exists in cache. Let's get a new one from AAD.")
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=config["scope"])

if "access_token" in result:
    # Calling graph using the access token
    graph_data = requests.get(  # Use token to call downstream service
        config["endpoint"],
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']}, ).json()
    print("Graph API call result: ")
    print(json.dumps(graph_data, indent=2))
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))  # You may need this when reporting a bug
```

The sample is retrieving a list of users from MS Graph, but it should be just a matter of adapting it to retrieve the list of emails of a specific user by  changing the "endpoint" parameter in the parameters.json file to:

```
"endpoint": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users//users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages"
```

You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) more information regarding the MS Graph request to list emails.

Answer (score 0):

register your app
get your tenant id from azure portal and disable mfa

```
application_id = "xxxxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
#authority_url = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
authority_url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
base_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/"
endpoint = base_url+"me"
scopes = ["User.Read"]
tenant_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+tenant_id+'/oauth2/token'

token_data = {
'grant_type': 'password',
'client_id': application_id,
'client_secret': client_secret,
'resource': 'https://graph.microsoft.com',
'scope':'https://graph.microsoft.com',
'username':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  # Account with no 2MFA
'password':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
}
token_r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
token = token_r.json().get('access_token')
print(token)
```